# Copy blocks from one drupal installation to another

Tags: blocks

With a lot of help from the users of this forum yesterday I managed to get my local installation running.

I have copied across the theme from the site I wish to base mine on (with the permission of the theme owner, so nothing dodgy is going on).

But when I go to Blocks, there are none present. If I look in the admin on the old site, there are a number of blocks that appear in the header (menu, search bar and so on). If I click on create new block on my install I get a blank form. Is there any way to copy existing blocks from the install I am mimicking to mine?

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are considered content, like nodes are. So basically you want to migrate content? You could work with [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) or [Block Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_export_import).

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll take a look shortly. the version of the old site I have won't allow me to add new modules for some reason, which may give me a problem